# How to verify responsiveness on IOS devices?

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive, inspect

Is there a way to check for responsiveness in IOS devices(including Iphone 11) without having access to a phone?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most reliable option will be Xcode which comes with safari emulation. If you have a Mac, great. Do that(if you want to, that is).

Other than that, you should check this answer to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38715654/10553945).